# C# regex.split method is adding empty string before parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex, tokenize

I have some code that tokenizes a equation input into a string array:

```
string infix = "( 5 + 2 ) * 3 + 4";
string[] tokens = tokenizer(infix, @"([\+\-\*\(\)\^\\])");
foreach (string s in tokens)
{
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Now here is the tokenizer function:

```
public string[] tokenizer(string input, string splitExp)
        {
            string noWSpaceInput = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s", "");
            Console.WriteLine(noWSpaceInput);
            Regex RE = new Regex(splitExp);
            return (RE.Split(noWSpaceInput));
        }
```

When I run this, I get all characters split, but there is an empty string inserted before the parenthesis chracters...how do I remove this?

//empty string here

(

5

+

2

//empty string here

)

*

3

+

4

Comment: For the record, it's not an empty space so much as a [`String.Empty`](http://www.ideone.com/vyuzI).

Comment: agreed title is not completely accurate...fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just filter them out:

```
public string[] tokenizer(string input, string splitExp)
{
    string noWSpaceInput = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s", "");
    Console.WriteLine(noWSpaceInput);
    Regex RE = new Regex(splitExp);
    return (RE.Split(noWSpaceInput)).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: well filtering is easy enough, but I would want a way with the regex and not building a new array.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is because you have nothing then a separator (i.e. at the beginning of the string is`(`), then two separator characters next to one another (i.e. `)*` in the middle). This is by design.

As you may have found with `String.Split`, that method has an optional enum which you can give to have it remove any empty entries, however, there is no such parameter with regular expressions. In your specific case you could simply ignore any token with a length of 0.

```
foreach (string s in tokens.Where(tt => tt.Length > 0))
{
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (if you don't want to filter the result):

```
tokenizer(infix, @"(?=[-+*()^\\])|(?<=[-+*()^\\])");
```

Perl demo:

```
perl -E "say join ',', split /(?=[-+*()^])|(?<=[-+*()^])/, '(5+2)*3+4'"
(,5,+,2,),*,3,+,4
```

Altho it would be better to use a match instead of split in this case imo.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `-` in your character class.

Comment: That is pretty epic regex skillz, what does ?<= and ?= do? Also this does not take care of the empty string at the beginning.

Comment: Those are [look-behind and look-ahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Matching things without including ("eating") them in the match it self.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one option would be to filter them out afterwards:

```
return RE.Split(noWSpaceInput).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries]  by the split

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string infix = "( 5 + 2 ) * 3 + 4";
        string[] results = infix.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var result in results)
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```